# Unresolved metas in for run in Agda hello-world

Tags: agda, agda-stdlib

I tried to compile the [hello-world](https://agda.readthedocs.io/en/v2.6.1.3/getting-started/hello-world.html#hello-world-in-agda) example with [Agda 2.6.1.3](https://www.stackage.org/lts-17.5/package/Agda-2.6.1.3) and [Agda stdlib 1.5](https://github.com/agda/agda-stdlib/releases/tag/v1.5). Below is the code:

```
module hello-world where

open import IO

main = run (putStrLn "Hello, World!")
```

When compiling with Agda (`agda --compile hello-world.agda`), the following error is reported:

```
Unsolved metas at the following locations:
  $HOME/hello-world.agda:5,8-11
```

The reported position (`5,8-11`) corresponds to token `run`.

I did not find any related information in both Agda and Agda-stdlib Issues, nor on SO or other websites. Is the documentation out-dated, or did I make any mistakes?

---

Note:

- The Agda compiler is installed with `stack install Agda` with resolver `lts-17.5`.
- I also tried manually compiling from GitHub sources (branch `release-2.6.1.3`).
- In `$HOME/.agda/libraries` I have:

  ```
  $HOME/agda-stdlib/standard-library.agda-lib
  ```
- In `$HOME/.agda/defaults` I have:

  ```
  standard-library
  ```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the problem described in the comment at https://github.com/agda/agda/issues/4250#issuecomment-771806949. The current workaround is to add an implicit argument to `run` as follows:

```
module hello-world where

open import IO
open import Level

main = run {0ℓ} (putStrLn "Hello, World!")
```

This issue will be fixed in the upcoming release of Agda 2.6.2 and the next version of the standard library.

Comment: Ah, thanks! In that issue, the error message is presented as a screenshot. That's probably why my searching on GitHub gave no results.

Comment: To import `0ℓ` only, use `open import Level using (0ℓ)`. It messed with other imports for me.